# C# / C++ - Methods under namespace

Tags: c#, c++, enums, difference

Let's say I have an enum named `ExitCodes`. I also want to have a method called `ErrorCodes.Quit`. In C++, you can put methods under namespace, while in C# you can't. So, you can have both the enum and the method under the namespace `ExitCodes` in C++, but in C# you're limited. I wanted to ask two questions about those differences.

1. Is there a workaround for this in C#? Can I achieve the same, somehow? I know I could make the class non-static, make the constructor private and then insanitate static instances of ExitCodes with values and a static method Quit, but that's too much work.
2. I want to be able to make custom types like it is in C++. For example, in C++ I can do:

   ```
   using exit_code_t = int;
   ```

I doubt it's possible in C#, but why not ask here.

Comment: There are namespaces in c#, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: And the second is possible, see [type alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @DStanley, ok, then no, you can't in c#, you would have to make a static class.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a workaround for this in C#?

Yes, put the method (and the Enum if you want) in a class instead of a namespace.  Syntactically it will look the same:

```
public class ExitCodes
{
    public enum ExitCodes
    {  
        ...  
    }


    public static void Quit()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use `ExitCodes.ExitCodes` and `ExitCodes.Quit()`;

> I want to be able to make custom types like it is in C++

In C++ that just gives an *alias* to the `int` type.  You can do the same thing in C#, but you have to use the actual type name, not the `int` keyword:

```
using System;

using MyInt = System.Int32;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // your code goes here
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyInt).ToString());  // will print System.Int32
    }
}
```

One difference in C# is that the alias only applies to the *current file*.  So it not *exactly* the same as the C++ alias/`typedef` but it's as close as you're going to get.

Comment: I believe `Quit()` will have to be static for it to the the same syntax as a namespace(not needing a `ExitCodes` object).